Fullcalendar eventColour on MySQL Title
I am currently running FullCalendar (V4? I'd be lying if I was certain on this!) on my website and I am trying to change the colour dynamically depending on the title of the event in the MySQL Database. I have tried a few things and have got to a point where it is able to recognise when the event matches the type I want to change the colour for. However, no matter what I try I can't quite seem to figure out the override for the colour on the actual calendar.
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00',
            plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            },
            editable: false,
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            displayEventEnd: {
                month: false,
                basicWeek: true,
                "default": true
            },
            eventTimeFormat: {
              hour: "numeric",
              minute: "2-digit",
              meridiem: "short",
          },

          eventRender: function(info) {
            if(info.event.title == "TitleToCompare") {
            backgroundColor: '#cecece'
            console.log(info.event.title);
        }
            var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                placement: 'top',
                trigger: 'hover',
                container: 'body',
            });
        },
        events: {
            url: 'privateEvents.php',
            failure: function() {
                document.getElementById('script-warning').style.display = 'block'
            }
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            document.getElementById('loading').style.display =
            bool ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
    });

        calendar.render();
    });

I have tried using eventColor, backgroundColor, eventBackgroundColor. I have also tried using a different thread on here which had a solution of adding a CSS element to it but it just then returns an error instead refusing to load in any of the events.
I have had a look at a lot of the documentation on the FullCalendar website but it doesn't seem to quite cover this scenario... Or I am blind!

This is javascript, not PHP. Please check tags before posting in the future. Is TitleToCompare in your console log? I would debug with breakpoints and see what is happening during execution.

Apologies on tags, its the PHP version of FullCalendar so felt somewhat relevant but take the point. Yes - it is showing the TitleToCompare in the log.

Is backgroundColor: '#cecece' setting and getting overwritten or not applying at all? Have you put a breakpoint in at that point in code and seen what the calendar has for color?

You're not even in an object context there, so I don't see how backgroundColor: '#cecece' could make any sense. I think you need something like info.event.setProp('backgroundColor', '#cecece'); here.

If you're looking to make changes to the event object, eventRender is too late for that to affect what's actually rendered - that's already happened, and the eventRender callback is your opportunity to modify the rendered HTML, not the event object. So either make it affect the HTML directly, or use the eventDataTransform callback instead - in there you can modify and return the event object, setting the backgroundColor property, which will then be used by fullCalendar when it does the rendering.

But yeah CBroe is right in that the syntax you've written also makes no sense - backgroundColor: '#cecece' by itself, outside an object literal declaration, doesn't do anything.

You have to specify color key in privateEvents.php file, which returns list of events.

References :
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new FullCalendar.Calendar(
    document.getElementById('calendar'), {
      initialDate: '2024-07-05',
      initialView: 'timeGridDay',
      slotDuration: "00:15:00",
      events: [{
          id: 1,
          title: "Demo 1",
          color: "#DCFFB7",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T13:00:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T13:15:00"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Demo 2",
          color: "#D9F2DB",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T13:15:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T13:30:00"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "Demo 3",
          color: "#F7A774",
          textColor: "#FFF",
          start: "2024-07-05T13:30:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T13:45:00"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: "Demo 1",
          color: "#DCFFB7",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T14:00:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T14:15:00"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          title: "Demo 2",
          color: "#D9F2DB",
          textColor: "#000",
          start: "2024-07-05T14:15:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T14:30:00"
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          title: "Demo 3",
          color: "#F7A774",
          textColor: "#FFF",
          start: "2024-07-05T14:30:00",
          end: "2024-07-05T14:45:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ).render();
});
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.14/index.global.min.js'></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>



